# void (*a)(char*, char*); is this a function?

Tags: c

```
 void  (*a)(char*, char*);
```

is this a function called a. returns void pointer?
in c?

Comment: You might want to bookmark [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=void++%28*a%29%28char+*%2C+char+*%29)

Comment: The above link does not actually point to that adress. This does: [cdecl.org/](https://cdecl.org/?q=void++%28*a%29%28char*%2C+char*%29%3B)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is declaration of a variable named `a`; it is a pointer to a function that takes two `char*` parameters and does not return anything.  You will need to assign an actual function to `a` before calling it.

Comment: No it doesn't; if `a` was a pointer to a function returning `void*`, the declaration would be `void *(*a)(char*, char*);`.

Answer (score 7):

This is a function *pointer* named `a`.  The function signature of `a` is a function that returns void and takes two `char *` arguments.

See [Function Pointer Tutorials](http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html#defi) for more information on function pointers.

Answer (score 4):

It's a pointer to a function, which takes 2x char pointers & returns void (see [cdecl.org](https://cdecl.org/?q=void++%28*a%29%28char*%2C+char*%29%3B))

Answer (score 3):

It is a function pointer. Example:

```
void someFunction(char* param1, char* param2) {
   // ...
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   char arg1[] = "Hello";
   char arg2[] = "World";
   void (*a)(char*, char*) = &someFunction;
   a(arg1, arg2);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a variable which is a *pointer* to a function returning nothing, which takes two arguments of type "pointer to char". The function pointer is named "a".

Answer (score 1):

No.

It is a pointer to a function that takes two strings and returns nothing.