# What does an asterisk before a function name mean?

Tags: c, operators, function-pointers

In the following lines of code, what does the asterisk in front of dup_func, free_func, and clear_free func, do?

```
void *(*dup_func)(void *);
void (*free_func)(void *);
void (*clear_free_func)(void *);
```

Comment: What language?  I'm guessing C, but who knows.

Comment: And here's what the first one means: [cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=void+*%28*dup_func%29%28void+*%29%3B)

Comment: possible duplicate of [void (*a)(char*, char*); is this a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546867/void-achar-char-is-this-a-function)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your examples it means they are [function pointers](http://www.newty.de/fpt/).

In a nutshell, they allow you to do things like this:

```
void example()
{
    printf("Example called!\n");
}

void call_my_function(void (*fun)())
{
    printf("Calling some function\n");
    (*fun)();
}

/* Later. */
call_my_function(example);
```

Comment: Note that empty parentheses are old-style (K&R C), obsoleted by C99. You should add `void` where you mean void.